# What is the $68^{th}$ term of the sequence- $1, 4, 5, 16, 17, 20,....................?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

Given sequence-  $1, 4, 5, 16, 17, 20, .........$

I have two guesses here.

Firstly, we see that the differences between two consecutive terms are $3, 1, 11, 1,$ and $3$. 
 So accordingly if we maintain a  **"sequence of differences"** it will turn out to be $3, 1, 11, 1, 3, 1, 11, 1, 3,.......$

thus, by adding the differences we can find the $68^{th}$ term of the **main sequence**  to be $273$.

I thought a second way to solve it.

in the given sequence  $1, 4, 5, 16, 17, 20, ........$

if we separate the $odd^{th}$ $(1st , 3rd, 5th,...etc)$ and even-th $(2nd, 4th, 6th,...etc)$ terms, we see that

the difference between two consecutive odd-th term keeps increasing by $4 [ 1, 5, 17,....],$

Similarly, a difference between two consecutive even terms keeps decreasing by $4.$
$[ 4, 16, 20......]. $

In this way, as $68^{th}$ term is an even-th term, so we follow the above rule and get, $68^{th}$ term $= -8036$

I am not completely sure whether any of my strategies is correct. 
So I need a correct answer

Comment: http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C4%2C5%2C16%2C17%2C20&sort=&language=english&go=Search
but I don't see how this might be meaningful

Comment: It is, as you remarked, a case of periodic difference sequence $[3,1,11,1,3,1,11,1,\cdots]$. So you need to study these sequences.

Comment: In general, just knowing the first $n$ entries in a sequence will not give you any way of knowing what even the $n+1$'st number is.  The only way to know for sure what the next entry is (or however many entries into the future) is to be told how the sequence is constructed.

Comment: Maybe your sequence be [A000695](http://oeis.org/A000695).

Comment: OK, in general, knowing the $n+1$ first entries, you always have a polynomial of degree $n$ (unique) which gives these entries (see answers below). This time, not in the least (unless it be zero) periodic neither its first differences (unless it be constant). All depends what is awaited.

Comment: The $68^{th}$ term is $272$, you are off by one. $1 , 4 , 5 , 16 , 17 , 20 , 21 , 32 , 33 , 36 , 37 , 48 , 49 , 52 , 53 , 64 , 65 , 68 , 69 , 80 , 81 , 84 , 85 , 96 , 97 , 100 , 101 , 112 , 113 , 116 , 117 , 128 , 129 , 132 , 133 , 144 , 145 , 148 , 149 , 160 , 161 , 164 , 165 , 176 , 177 , 180 , 181 , 192 , 193 , 196 , 197 , 208 , 209 , 212 , 213 , 224 , 225 , 228 , 229 , 240 , 241 , 244 , 245 , 256 , 257 , 260 , 261 , 272$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Representing the terms in base $4$, we have

$$1_{10} = 1_{4}$$
$$4_{10} = 10_{4}$$
$$5_{10} = 11_{4}$$
$$16_{10} = 100_{4}$$
$$17_{10} = 101_{4}$$
$$20_{10} = 110_{4}$$

so to get the $68th$ term in the sequence we represent $68$ in binary as $1000100$, pretend it's a base $4$ representation, then convert back to decimal to get $4112.$

EDIT: Ah, I should have read the comments first. @Amin$235$ beat me to this by $5$ hours.

Comment: I'm happy to have this as an answer, not merely as some obscure link-only comment (and OEIS is currently down).

Comment: @MvG please be fair!

Comment: @Amin235: Sorry if this sounded harsh regarding your comment. My point is that having an answer posted as an answer is desirable, even if the core of the answer was already present in a comment. And while a link-only comment is probably appropriate here, it's not enough for an answer. This here lets me understand the sequence while staying on the same page. I shouldn't have called your comment “obscure”, sorry. I'd have been happy if you had fleshed out that link by paraphrasing the relevant aspects, thus turning your comment into a full answer similar to this one here.

Comment: @MvG, You know, I could mentioned in the comment that the numbers are obtained by sums of distinct powers of 4, but working with sequences taught me It is possible that the numbers $1, 4, 5, 16, 17, 20$ can be generated with other sequence or something else, that is different from  A000695. By the way, I respect to your attitude and maybe you right.

Answer (score 2):

Using the "sequence of difference" hypothesis, the pattern has a period of $4$ and the difference between every fourth term is $16$. Then the $68^{th}$ term is $$1+17\times16-1=\color{green}{272},$$ as you start from $1$, add $68/4$ periods and backtrack by one term (correction $-1$).

---

Without this hypothesis and without further information, the $68^{th}$ term can be proven to be $42$.